# Change static ip address in netplan problem

Tags: netplan, ip

I use ubuntu server 20.04.
First i set static ip address in **/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml** for the enp2s0 interface. Apply the changes good and i use the server for a cuple of weeks.
The ip addres look like this:

enp2s0:
addresses:
-10.0.0.14/24
-192.9.100.14/24

I decide to change the ip addres to another, i edit again the netplan file and set the new ip number:

enp2s0:
addresses:
-10.0.0.15/24
-192.9.100.15/24

But when i apply changes, i still view the old ip address:
I ping 10.0.0.14 and stil response... in the system information when i loging whith putty (ssh service) i can view the TWO NUMBERS !!! i put "ip a" and again i stil view the old and the new ip number !!!
What i`m doing wrong?

Comment: Post your yaml. 

Are there other *yaml files in the netplan directory?

Comment: ufff... bingo, there is another yaml in the directory...sory